# Can XSD add a constraint for comparing two elements?

Tags: xsd, xsd-1.1

Can XSD add a constraint for comparing two elements ?
Say I have Begin End under DataRangeType I want to add a constraint saying `Begin <= End`. Is this doable ?

BTW I am using XMLSpy 2013.

```
<xs:complexType name="DataRangeType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Begin" type="xs:date"/>
        <xs:element name="End" type="xs:date"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's doable in XSD 1.1 by means of assertions.  I do not believe the constraint is expressible in XSD 1.0.

[Addendum] You ask for an example.  Here you are.

```
<xs:complexType name="DataRangeType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Begin" type="xs:date"/>
    <xs:element name="End" type="xs:date"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:assert test="Begin &lt;= End"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: I am using xsd 1.1 and can you give me a example please?

Comment: I have tried the assert but XMLSPy gives me 'Element <xs:assert> is not allowed under element <xs:complexType>.'

Comment: Sounds like your software is telling you it doesn't support XSD 1.1. How confident are you that it does?